# Submit data to database using Ajax and jQuery - codeigniter submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, codeigniter

I am creating a codeigniter project where i get number of items from my database and each item has a submit button clicking on which the data are stored into the database using AJAX and jQuery. 
Now, the problem is that when i submit any item only the data of 1st form is sent to the method that inserts data to the database please provide some solution regarding the same.  my code is as under:

Model:

```
<?php
class Products_model extends CI_Model{

    function get_all(){

        $results = $this->db->get('tblUtensils')->result();

        return $results;
    }
    function get($id){
        $results = $this->db->get_where('tblUtensils', array('pkItemID' => $id))->result();
        $result = $results[0];

        return $result;
    }
}


?>
```

View:

```
<body>

    <div id="products">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product): 
        $id=$product->pkItemID;
        ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo form_open('shop/add', 'id="form"'); ?>


                    <div><?php echo form_input('name_' . $id, $product->fldName , 'id='.'"'.'name_' . $id.'"');?></div>
                    <div><?php echo form_input('desc_' . $id, $product->fldDescription , 'id='.'"'.'desc_' . $id.'"');?></div>
                    <div><?php echo form_input('rate_' . $id, $product->fldRateMB1 , 'id='.'"'.'rate_' . $id.'"');?></div>
                    <div><?php echo form_input('Qty_' . $id, 0, 'id='.'"'.'qty_' . $id.'"');?></div>
                    <?php echo form_hidden('id', $product->pkItemID, 'id="ID"'); ?>

                    <?php echo form_submit('action', 'Add','id="submit"');?>

                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- try 2 -->
    <script type = "text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <------this will restrict the page refresh
     var form_data = {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        name: $('#name_' + id).val(),
        rate: $('#rate_' + id).val(),
        qty: $('#qty_' + id).val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('shop/add'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
              alert("success");
        }

   });
   return false;
 });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php 

class Shop extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->model('Products_model');
        $data['products'] = $this->Products_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('products',$data);


    }

    function add(){
        //$this->load->model('Products_model');
        //$product = $this->Products_model->get($this->input->post('id'));

        $insert = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),//<-- also not able to get this id from ajax post request
        'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('rate'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        );
        $this->cart->insert($insert);//<--insert item into cart
        $query// to insert into database

        //redirect('shop');
        }

 }
?>
```

Many questions have been posted before regarding codeigniter and ajax but none did provide solution to my problem so i am posting this question, appreciate your help.

Comment: please read about DOM here : http://kangax.github.io/domlint/

your forms having same Id.

Comment: so whats the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many ways of dealing with this and finally the thing that worked for me was as under:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        var id = (this.id);
        var form_data = {            //repair
            id: id,
            name: $('#name_' + id).val(),
            rate: $('#rate_' + id).val(),
            qty: $('#qty_' + id).val()
        };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('shop/add'); ?>",//repair
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data, // $(this).serialize(); you can use this too
        success: function(msg) {
              alert("success..!! or any stupid msg");
        }

   });
   return false;

});

</script>
```

Comment: I added class="submit" and id="id" to my submit button so now i can use its onClick event to get the id which is in-turn the value i need to assign to my variable "id"..thank u all guys for your help too..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php echo form_open('shop/add', 'id="form"'); ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo form_open('shop/add', 'id="form_' . $id . '"'); ?>
```

This gives different id's for each forms.